Wavefunction in amorphous solids
(Originally this question, here I'll present just one of the questions in answer to one of the comments.)
Bloch's theorem applies to periodic potentials and therefore to periodic lattices. But not all solids have a periodic structure, in particular, amorphous solids are non-periodic. Is there a general way to describe this wavefunction in a case like this?
Obviously there is no translational symmetry due to the lack of periodicity. But if there is no preferred direction, what about a rotational symmetry? Could that be used in a similar manner?

"Is there a general way to describe this wavefunction in a case like this?" If you can specify the fixed aperiodic structure, for example as a set of ion positions in real space, then you can (in principle) calculate the wave function. Of course, for an aperiodic system you would have to specify every ion position and thus could not specify an entire solid. But if you are OK with a small cluster of ions as representative of the solid then you can use real-space techniques to numerically solve the problem (in a single-particle approximation like real-space DFT).

"what about a rotational symmetry" Generally, there will be no rotational symmetry.
